# Eloquent Showing pivot

Tags: laravel, pivot, eloquent

for some weird reason building this model with Eloquent is hiding the Pivot that I am requiring explicitly in the relation (This Model is called Match):

```
public function scorers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Player::class,
        'match_players',
        'match_id'
    )->withPivot(
        'goals'
    )->where(
        'goals', '>', 0
    );
}

public function scopeComplete($query)
{
    return $query->with(
        'homeTeam',
        'awayTeam',
        'scorers'
    );
}
```

The problem is the json result of scorers is as follows

```
"scorers": [
  {
    "id": 196,
    "name": "Tino",
    "surname": "Heck",
    "age": 24
  },...
```

And is hiding the pivot (goals) team_id and goals which should appear on each object inside a nested object called pivot, did anyone came across some problem like this? I cat find anything around here. Something like

```
"scorers": [
  {
    "id": 196,
    "name": "Tino",
    "surname": "Heck",
    "age": 24,
    "pivot": {
      "goals": 3
    }
  },...
```

Db structure is

```
Match
- id
- ..
Players
- id
- ...
MatchPlayer
- player_id
- match_id
- goals
```

The result inside scorers is correct, so I get the actual player where goals > 0, but not the pivot I am looking for

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I found the error, the problem was that Iwas hiding pivots on Player Model :(
So the lesson here is the $hidden array property that counts is the one on the relation model rather than the one on the Parent (Match in this case)